# Showing the value a plotted function achieves at the right-most point of the plot domain

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm plotting results from NDSolve, and I'd like to clip them with their value at the point where the line is clipped.
So where the curve ends at the edge of the plot, there would be a number indicating the y-value of the curve at that point.

If that's not possible or too complicated, how can I include the end value of the plot in the legend?

here's my plot command:

```
    Plot[{
Evaluate[Ca //. {parameters}] //. soln,
Evaluate[Cb //. {parameters}] //. soln,
Evaluate[Cc //. {parameters}] //. soln,
Evaluate[Ci //. {parameters}] //. soln,
Evaluate[Cd //. {parameters}] //. soln,
Evaluate[Ce //. {parameters}] //. soln,
Evaluate[Ch //. {parameters}] //. soln}, {w, 0, 500}, 
PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLegends -> {Subscript[C, methane], Subscript[C, ethane], 
Subscript[C, ethylene], Subscript[C, inerts], Subscript[C, 
benzene], Subscript[C, naphthalene], Subscript[C, hydrogen]}, 
AxesLabel -> {"w", "C"}, AspectRatio -> 0.8, 
PlotLabel -> "molar concentration vs catalyst weight"]
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. Do you want the number inside or outside the plot region? Do you care if it's Framed? Would you be comfortable setting it as a custom `Ticks` or `FrameTicks` function? Why not just set it as an `Epilog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you want, but perhaps this will suffice. Since you didn't provide your equations, I'm going to take an example from the documentation

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1.2}, y, {x, 0, 25}];
```

Note that the solution is a list of solutions, so to get the numerical value of the solution at a point, you need to extract it from the list it sits in.

```
y[25] /. s

(* {0.0577224} *)
```

You can use [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html) to put the value you want in as a text label.

```
With[{end = First[y[25] /. s]}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 25}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.02, 
  Epilog -> Text[ToString@end, {25, end + 0.1}]]]
```

This actually chops off some of the number, but you didn't want those significant figures anyway, did you? In any case, you can always finesse this with [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberForm.html), [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Style.html), etc and tweak the position to taste.

[image]